# Transferring java application to server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, web-applications, server

I have created a java application in intellij ide. The application is working well. Now that my application is ready I want to transfer my java application from my machine to server and make it live. I have one server, domain and all the basic rights in the server. Can any one help me figuring out?

**I am very new in this part. I dont know anything about hosting my own website and application.**

Comment: You first have to install java and an application server (jetty, tomcat, wildfly, ...) to deploy your application.

Comment: where i have to do this.. and I am talking about real server

Comment: What type of app have you written?

Comment: its a dropwizard application. initally supporting web service but will be extended to website

Comment: What kind of server is it? Windows? Linux? If it's a dropwizard application then you probably just need to install java

Comment: I choose 000webhost.com service but i think its wrong to choose this. Can you suggest any?

Comment: Looks like they only have PHP etc on those machines. You better switch to another service.

Comment: Look at one of these: https://hostadvice.com/lp/hosting-companies/java/?creative=208883061052&targetid=kwd-300323108103&matchtype=e&device=c&campaignid=837723726&adgroupid=39560129021&feeditemid=&loc_physical_ms=1012489&loc_interest_ms=&network=g&devicemodel=&placement=&keyword=java%20application%20hosting&target=&aceid=&adposition=1t1&gclid=CjwKCAjw3f3NBRBPEiwAiiHxGJsE-iQ7TFfWloN2ekaLIxlIQxobGTjPNkdCb7q9gk76LHUdgzX-BRoCzjQQAvD_BwE

Comment: Is it possible on one providing linux3.2?

Comment: And one thing more can you explain difference in hosting only a website and hosting an application

Comment: You have many more than one question. Stackoverflow is designed to be different from a forum with a long thread of question/answers. Its focus is on having specific questions that need specific answers. This way the same question/answer can be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what technology you use. If you use application that needs to be deploy into servlet container you can deploy it onto e.g. Tomcat.

Whatever technology you use you definiately should build your application - it also depends on what building system you use.
E.g.fFor gradle, you can use `gradlew build`.
For maven: `mvn compile`.

Tell us more details about technology you use to allow us to help you.

Comment: can you suggest some host which support java application?

Comment: OpenShift, Heroku

Comment: are they free? so that i can test my application

Comment: They are free in some limitations. You can check the tutorial for example how to deply spring boot application on my blog (https://medium.com/@pablo127/deploy-spring-boot-application-to-openshift-3-next-gen-2b311f55f0c5). I describe there the limitations and some adventages of OpenShift Starter

Comment: hey can you tell me how to go with dropwizard application in openshift

Comment: build jar or war and deploy it just like I described in my tutorial.

Comment: What do you mean initial cloning? Which part do you ask about?

Comment: Hey Its done.. I was not creating procfile correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a java application (Dropwizard) and first need a server to run it on, which means that it must be a server with java installed or where you can install it yourself.

Then you need to transfer the application "fat" jar (typically you find this in the `target` directory, depending on how you built it) to this server and start it with `java -jar my-application.jar`.

Then you need to make sure that the port that the application runs on is available externally. This usually means that you need to have a web server installed (commonly nginx or httpd) which redirects from port 80 or 443 to the port of your application.

Only then is you app "live".